# Text mining for text matching

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-mining, nlp, text-mining

I m new in text analysis and need your advice to help medical students to write properly and correctly. The students describe sicknesses as they  observe them; however, they must use an "official sickness description". I have the data collected from the students and the correct data. Let me explain:

I have a csv table1 containing 300K rows / one column : each row is the description of health condition written by students ( they can be redundant).

I have an other table2 containing almost 200K rows and 3 columns
Column 1: the official name of the condition ( the correct one the student should use)
Column 2: a code ( number) 
Column 3: the translation of "the official name of the condition" in another language.

The idea is to start from table1 and match each row with N official names (with their codes and translation). Let's say 5 official names ranked by distance computation.

I am confused:
Should I go for a recommendation engine or a search/rank algorithms?

What are the steps you can identify to accomplish this task?

PS: the final output might be an API where student start to write the description of the sickness and obtain a list of choices/recommendations where they can pick one. 
I hope I was clear ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all I will definitely test the FuzzyWuzzy Lib. Meanwhile please take a look on the code I have made yesterday ( it can be enhanced , Go ahead if you can make it better : –

```
#define function to read the CSV files
def GetDocument(link):
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(link, encoding = "ISO-8859-1", sep = ';')
    return dataframe
#define function convert text/CSV data to lists 
def ColumnToList(column):
    return column.tolist()
#read document csv 
document1 = GetDocument('C:/Users/smegrhi/Desktop/DOC1.csv')
document2 = GetDocument('C:/Users/smegrhi/Desktop/DOC2.csv')
#get columns into lists
list1 = ColumnToList(document1['DIA_LBL'])
list2 = ColumnToList(document2['ICD10_LBL_FR'])

#Data pre-processing

def ProcessText(sentence):

    #Convert to lower case
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    #Convert www.* or https?://* to URL
    sentence = re.sub('((www\.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','',sentence)
#Convert 
    sentence = re.sub('@[^\s]+','',sentence)
#Remove additional white spaces
    sentence = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', sentence)
#Replace 
    sentence = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', sentence)
    return sentence


#execute
for i,text in enumerate(list1):
    res = ProcessText(text)
    list1[i] = res

#vectorize the data
WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')
#function vectorize data
def text_to_vector(text):
    words = WORD.findall(text)
    return Counter(words)

#calculate similarity
def get_cosine(vec1, vec2):
    intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
    numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])

    sum1 = sum([vec1[x]**2 for x in vec1.keys()])
    sum2 = sum([vec2[x]**2 for x in vec2.keys()])
    denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)

    if not denominator:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return float(numerator) / denominator

# compare sentence from list 1 with list 2 : Choose Indication from Data/DOC1 

text1 = list1[1]
#text1 = shigellose à shigella dysenteriae
vector1 = text_to_vector(text1)
listCosine = []
for i,text in enumerate(list2):
    vector2 = text_to_vector(text)
    cosine = get_cosine(vector1, vector2)
    listCosine.append(cosine)
```

The results are not that bad neither good ...
Your suggestions ?

Comment: Try preprocessing the student entries. Also, any reason why you are using "ISO-8859-1" over "UTF-8"?

Comment: I have some French characters ... this is why I use  "ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 1):

[FuzzyWuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) would be a good python library for this purpose. A code example from the GitHub readme:

```
>>> choices = ["Atlanta Falcons", "New York Jets", "New York Giants", "Dallas Cowboys"]
>>> process.extract("new york jets", choices, limit=2)
    [('New York Jets', 100), ('New York Giants', 78)]
>>> process.extractOne("cowboys", choices)
    ("Dallas Cowboys", 90)
```

I imagine you would like to use the `extract` function with limit 5 with `choices` being set equal to all the 'official names' from your table2 csv file.

Details on installation and use are at the link above.

Comment: Thank you all I will definitely test the FuzzyWuzzy Lib. Meanwhile please take a look on the code I have made yesterday ( it can be enhanced , Go ahead if you can make it better :

Answer (score 1):

> The idea is to start from table1 and match each row with N official names (with their codes and translation). Let's say 5 official names ranked by distance computation.

I would recommend against using an ML classifier because you're likely to exclude some of the 200k official names if only 5 options are given back.

There are many fuzzy text matching algorithms to match your rows to an official name. [FuzzyWuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy)'s and several other algorithms are based on the [Levenshtein](https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~kirk/cs1501/Pruhs/Spring2006/assignments/editdistance/Levenshtein%20Distance.htm) distance. You can use a for-loop to go through the 200k official names. Depending on how much text there is this might take a while. Sort the list and slice/pop values that have to low scores, and you will have the top 5 best matching official names for a row. I guess you want to rank the frequency of each official name and return the highest ranked as a first result.

Because the health descriptions given by the students can be redundant, you might want run a [Zipf ranking algorithm](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1705/1705.07890.pdf) to filter more common words.

This is answer is far from complete. Comments are welcome.